# I am not seeing the Appium Server Log over CMD Console

Tags: java, android, npm, sdk, appium

Here is My Code:

```java
package abhishekmaurya.appium;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;

public class AppiumBasics {
    
    @Test
    public void AppiumTest() throws MalformedURLException {
        
        UiAutomator2Options Options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        Options.setDeviceName("abhishekphone");
        Options.setApp("C:\\Users\\abhshm\\eclipse-workspace\\appium\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\resources\\ApiDemos-debug.apk");      
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), Options);
        
        
    }

}
```

Also this code is for opening a app in Android SDK Emulator . that's also not working

Only this is shown in Console Output:

[image]

Below is My Environment Variable Snippet:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello All, Above issue is resolved after using 8.6.0 Java-Client for Appium 2.1.3 version.